# How to remove rows based on both condition and string?

Tags: r

I require to remove rows based on a string and a numeric value. In this case, a `comment` string and ID = 1

My dataset

```
ID  Value 
1   commentmg/l
1   32 mg/l
2   154 mg/ml
1   commentmg/l
3   54 u/l
8   1 l
```

Desired output

```
ID  Value 
1   32 mg/l
2   154 mg/ml
3   54 u/l
8   1 l
```

So far im able to remove all the `comment` by using

```
df = df %>%  
  filter(!grepl('comment', Value ))
```

But im requiring to add an extra condition based on ID

ADDENDUM: the filter idea works but will only keep the rows with other ID's

Comment: You should explain whether you want to keep or drop cases with ID==1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    filter(!(str_detect(Value, 'comment') & ID == 1))
```

-outut

```
ID     Value
1  1   32 mg/l
2  2 154 mg/ml
3  3    54 u/l
4  8       1 l
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 8L), Value = c("commentmg/l", 
"32 mg/l", "154 mg/ml", "commentmg/l", "54 u/l", "1 l")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: thanks. please see addendum i just made on the question

Comment: @AndresMora the code gives me the expected as in the new data

Answer (score 0):

What about `& ID == 1`?

```
> df %>%
+     filter(!(ID == 1 & grepl("comment", Value)))
  ID     Value
1  1   32 mg/l
2  2 154 mg/ml
3  3    54 u/l
4  8       1 l
```

Comment: thanks. please see addendum i just made on the question

Comment: @AndresMora See my udpate